# Netgear WNR1000v4 Keeps Disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've updated the firmware, still problems. I've tried hard reseting it, still problems. I've tried wired connection instead of wireless, still problems. The only way I get good internet is to stop using router and just plug into wire coming into building so it's definitely the router. I've checked user log, I'm only one using it. I have 150Mb/s download, 150Mb/s upload; using router I get 20 Mb/s download and maybe 8Mb/s upload but upload drops to 0 for a couple seconds every ~5 minutes. Router is rated for 150Mb/s so really performing sub par. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's no alternative firmware for this model - Get yourself a TL-WR841N then install openwrt. Cheapest and most reliable router out at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model and though it worked great for a couple years, now having horrible packet loss.  We live in a crowded area and I assume this is interference.  I have just switched the channel from '3' to '11' on the 'Wireless' screen in the admin page, and for the moment, things are much better.